# Update query not working propertly using namedquery in jpa

Tags: java, jpa

I'm trying to update a simple table using jpa. I have written a jpa namedquery for it

```
@NamedQuery(name="updatedetails",query="update myentity set enddesc=?, startdesc=? Where id=?")
```

My code is as follows

```
em.createNamedQuery("updatedetails",myentity.class).serParameter(1, "abcd").serParameter(2,"gjvg").serParameter(3, "gghjj").executeUpdate();
```

myentity is my class name

It throws me the following error

```
Encountered "=" at character but expected ["."] While parsing the query
```

Is there anything wrong with the query

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe that JPA named queries should use actual names are parameter placeholders, rather than `?`, the latter which is used in prepared statements.  So something like this should work:

```
@NamedQuery(name="updatedetails",query="update myentity set enddesc = :enddesc, startdesc = :startdesc Where id = :id")

List<myentity> results = em.createNamedQuery("updatedetails", myentity.class)
                           .setParameter("enddesc", "abcd")
                           .setParameter("startdesc", "gjvg")
                           .setParameter("id", "gghjj")
                           .getResultList();
```

As side note, you should probably make your class names begin with uppercase letters, i.e. call it `MyEntity`, rather than what you currently have.

Comment: Yeah right. Done in that fashion. But it's not updating and not throwing any errors. Is there anything needs to be changed from executeupdate

Answer (score 1):

```
em.createNamedQuery("updatedetails",myentity.class).serParameter(1, "abcd").serParameter(2,"gjvg").serParameter(3, "gghjj").executeUpdate();
```

Instead of `serParameter` use `setParameter`, should work.

Answer (score 0):

write this code in model class

```
 @NamedQuery(name = "new_ticket_bat.UpdateflagAutres", query = "UPDATE new_ticket_bat t set t.status_AUTRE='0' WHERE t.id= :id")
<br>
```

write  this code in you service class

```
 static void updateflagAutres(String id) {
       DataBaseTools dbTools = new DataBaseTools("databaseOv");
        try {
        Query q=dbTools.em.createNamedQuery("new_ticket_bat.UpdateflagAutres");
            q.setParameter("id", id);
            q.executeUpdate();
            dbTools.em.getTransaction().commit();
            dbTools.em.close();
         } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            Tools.traiterException(Tools.getStackTrace(ex));
        } 
    }
```